# Derivatives and functions

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous non decreasing functions defined on $\Bbb{R}$ such that $f''(x)= g(x)$ and $g''(x)= f(x)$. Suppose $f(x)g(x)$ is linear in $x$ in $(a,b)$. Then prove that
$$f(x)=g(x)=0 \quad\forall x\in (a,b)$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792089/tough-calculus-problem-with-functions-such-that-fx-gx-and-gx-f

Comment: Try computing $(fg)''$ using the product rule.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)g(x)=kx$, then
$$f'g+fg'=k$$
and
$$f''g+2f'g'+fg''=f^2+g^2+2f'g'=0$$
Differentiate again to get
$$2ff'+2gg'+2ff'+2gg'=0$$
So $f^2+g^2=k'$. Then
$$(f(x)+g(x))^2=2kx+k'$$
for all $x\in \Bbb R$, but this is possible olny if $k=0$ (if not, R.H.S. could be negative). We see also that $k'\geq 0$.

Now, suppose that there exists some $x_0\in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$. Then, $g(x_0)=0$ and $f(x_0)=\pm\sqrt {k'}$. That is, $f$ can reach only three values: $0$, $\sqrt{k'}$ and $-\sqrt{k'}$. Since $f$ is continuous, it actually reaches only one of them, so $f$ is constant. Then $f=f''''=0$, and $g=f''=0$.